# Docker compose, Postgres/PGAdmin setup

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

I'm trying to get an example app from https://trpc.io/docs/example-apps to work.  The catch is that I wanted to run the database in docker because I use a Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2) Ubuntu environment.  It's using postgres.  This is a fairly new machine and I know I have done this in the past in pure linux.

I had hoped to use as it looked good at a quick glance:
https://github.com/felipewom/docker-compose-postgres.git

My full code is here: https://github.com/ScorpIan555/simple-trpc-w-app-router
there are some slight modifications, but I was able to replicate this exact same error in both Felipe's example repo, as well as my own.

.env

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DB=postgres
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=[xxx]@gmail.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password
```

Error message:

```
2023-12-30 07:30:49 [2023-12-30 12:30:49 +0000] [93] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 93
2023-12-30 07:30:51 [2023-12-30 12:30:51 +0000] [93] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 93)
2023-12-30 07:30:51 ERROR  : Failed to create the directory /var/lib/pgadmin/sessions:
2023-12-30 07:30:51            [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/pgadmin/sessions'
2023-12-30 07:30:51 HINT   : Create the directory /var/lib/pgadmin/sessions, ensure it is writeable by
2023-12-30 07:30:51          'pgadmin', and try again, or, create a config_local.py file
2023-12-30 07:30:51          and override the SESSION_DB_PATH setting per
2023-12-30 07:30:51          https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/8.1/config_py.html
2023-12-30 07:30:51 [2023-12-30 12:30:51 +0000] [94] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 94
```

I understand that the /var/lib/ dir is owned by root.  I don't know much about pgadmin, but it looks like the postgres db protocol (?) might be trying to set up a session in the container once it's running, which would be expected behavior.

Given that container file systems should be read only, I was trying to follow the error message and create the `config_local.py` file, but had a permissions error when I set up a Dockerfile and did `RUN touch config_local.py`.  Maybe there's something dumb I'm just forgetting?

Comment: https://github.com/ScorpIan555/simple-trpc-w-app-router leads to a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several problems with the [`docker-compose-postgres` repository](https://github.com/felipewom/docker-compose-postgres.git) that make it not a great example, starting with the fact that it us using bind mounts for storage rather than named volumes. Just briefly noting all of the issues:

1. By using bind mounts rather than named volumes, access is controlled by the ownership and permissions of your local directories. This will often lead to conflicts, and there's no good reason for it in this case (because there's no compelling reason that you need direct access to either the postgres or pgadmin backend storage).

   I strongly suspect your permission issues are due to the use of bind mounts, and I think that replacing those with named volumes will solve your problem. I don't have access to a WSL environment in which to test this theory.
2. You don't need to explicitly create a network to be shared by the services in your compose file; `docker compose` does that for you *by default*.
3. I don't think this is a good example of using the `env-file` option. Since the file itself simply references other environment variables, it's nothing but another point of indirection. We can use compose's default support of a `.env` to better effect.

I would probably rewrite the file to look something like this:

```
services:
  database:
    image: 'docker.io/postgres:latest'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - 15432:5432
    volumes:
      - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
 
  pgadmin:
    image: 'docker.io/dpage/pgadmin4:latest'
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - 15080:80
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin/

volumes:
  pg-data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

If you create a `.env` that looks like:

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@example.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=secret
```

And bring things up like this:

```
docker compose up
```

Then docker will automatically apply the variables in your `.env` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, removing the bind mounts was the fix.  I just wanted to get this example working so I could play with the trpc part a bit and hadn't thought too much about it, so i appreciate the help.